# How can I use aptitude to install Nagios?

Tags: 10.04, apt, aptitude, nagios3

I've seen several guides online which describe downloading and building Nagios on Ubuntu servers. Is there also an aptitude package I could use to install Nagios 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find nagios3 packages with the command:

```
aptitude search nagios3
```

Or just:

```
aptitude search nagios
```

To install it, run:

```
aptitude install nagios3 nagios-plugins nagios-plugins-basic nagios-plugins-standard nagios-plugins-extra
```